# Employer asked me to work overtime to finish the project before I leave the company

Tags: professionalism, employer, overtime

I work in a small company and I am the only developer. 8h a day and 5 days a week. I am paid per hour (~4€)

My contract expires in one month. When the employer asked me wheter I wanted to renew or not, I politely refused saying that I will leave the company after the contract end date.

I guess he got a bit mad since he started raising his voice and telling me something like "Karma will get me for not having told him before". However I think one month notice period is enough.

I am currently working on a big project and he wants me to finish it before I leave. So he stated I may have to work on saturdays and do overtime in order to finish the project. How do I professionaly refuse?

Comment: Do you get paid for overtime as part of your contract?

Comment: My contract doesn't include overtime, however the employer also said that those hours are going to be paid

Comment: What happens if you decline?   Is it a big deal if said consequence happens?

Comment: 4 euro per hour?! I would not consider overtime even if it was paid. Smile and firmly refuse, if he is not a fool then he is trying to make a fool of you. Of course you can be open to a contracting position AFTER you finished working there.

Comment: @Keith nothing bad should happen, I am anyway leaving in a month

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti from your name I can tell we both are from the same country, my contract is 4€ because it is the so called 'stage'

Comment: @Twothousandandseven then it seems that if you want to work more hours, get paid more, and leave on a good note, you'll do it.    But it really depends on if you want to.

Comment: Yes, I don't live in Italy but I'm from there. If it's a stage then the answer is even more straightforward: no overtime at all. You already worked more than required (by law), you had no PTO, sick days and pension contributions. Moreover stage is by definition a learning experience, employer MUST not rely on you to produce work. Just say "no" and move on. If you are the only resource to finish a project then he completely failed in his role.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti what is this Stage?  I'd ask as a separate question, except that I don't even know enough to ask the question right.  If you'd be willing to make a self-answered question for this, that would be delightful.

Comment: @ben something in between an internship and a trainship. It's usually paid REALLY low and you do not have PTO, sick days and contributions. It is regulated to avoid employers to take advantage of young employees but unfortunately in Italy (AFAIK) it's often abused and they often need to work overtime and produce actual delivers (which, strictly speaking, is borderline to be illegal)

Comment: 4€ an hour? In Italy? That's insulting!! Even for an internship (funny it's stage in french too). Even Indians would find this insulting!!!!
Either he gives something reasonnable (say 20€) or he can fuck off. I don't think it's even legal to ask for that. It wouldn't be in France, as it is under the minimum wage and not in the stage convention.

Comment: @Pierre In Italy (as far as I can remember...) the minimum salary for stages is extremely low (and in some regions it's fixed). With very low I mean around x00 € per month , in theory just to cover your expenses because you're not actually _working_ but _learning_. Unfortunately some employers do not top on that _minimum_ and - like in this case - they expect you to complete actual work.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti : yes but any extra hour is outside the stage convention, so... this does not apply. Any additional hour is a working hour.

Comment: @Pierre it's not that easy with the Italian law. Legally a _tirocinante_ (the one going through the trainship) cannot work overtime and when they do is ALWAYS unpaid. If both parties agree then the employer can _declare_ that OP needs to work overtime TO LEARN (again, then, UNPAID). Of course employer might add (because of his own _generosity_)  _something_ on the top of the existing reimbursement for expenses but it's aligned with the previous (low) values because employer can claim back that money as tax deductions. In practice OP worked unpaid overtime (see his previous question)...

Comment: ..., he will now work overtime paid very little to complete a project when - by law - he should ONLY learn (see later) and employer is completely reimbursed (at the end of the fiscal year the employer will pay exactly ZERO for OP's work).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti : then just ask him if the extra hours he wants you to work are worth less than the hours of the person who cleans the floor. ;-)

Answer (score 15):

> I'm sorry, but I have other obligations outside of work that prohibit
>   me from working on the project outside of the 8hours per day I'm already doing. I don't think the project can be done
>   in the time I have left, so I would like to start documentation or a
>   transition plan so that the next developer can pick up where I left
>   off with as little confusion as possible. Is that ok with you?

Don't let some jerk strong arm you. What is the worst they can do, fire you? Unless you desperately need this person for a reference or you are breaching your contract, say that overtime is not a possibility, finishing the project is not possible, but you will do your best to get it into a place where it can be handed off.

Comment: I strongly second this answer and would like to elaborate a bit : this project is not your responsibility. As a developer, you're often sold that a project should be "your baby", your responsibility, that it's unprofessional to leave it unfinished, that you should see it through the end. No. As long as you work your hours and you do good work, that's enough. Don't let your boss guilt you in doing more. You really don't have to, and in your case I'd say it isn't worth it.

Answer (score 4):

If they had contracted you through the end of the project instead of on a time basis they would have protected themselves. Just say no, "I am going to choose not to work overtime, but I am happy to discuss alternative approaches to ensuring the project is completed successfully"

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you were employed as outsource to help the project right? if so you are under no obligation to work overtime or care about the project future 1 month is more than enough notice your boss is just being a jerk just go to your normal schedule and politely decline to stay he can do absolutely nothing to force you finish the project

If you were employed to finish the project and the contract says so then you have to finish and work whatever time necessary

Comment: My contract just says I need to work there until a certain date. I was employed as "IT Guy" and the project started after I got there

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably would have done it when I was starting out, because I wanted a good reference and wanted to finish the project.

I'm not saying you should.
~$5 USD / hour is lower than training wage here, so I don't know why he'd expect to get a completed project from you.

With my current life experience, I would not advise you to finish the project on your weekends... because I'm not sure you'll get a good reference even if you do (based on the reaction you describe).